# tooltip jquery method not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am running my App on Internet Explorer. There seems to be some issue with JQuery method:

```
$('.tooltip-demo').tooltip({  
  selector: "a[rel=tooltip]"  
})
```

for which, i get the following error on the javascript console:

Object doesn't support property or method **tooltip**

What can be the cause of this error? please help.

Comment: tried that as well.. dint work. Actually, the error is in the first line of the above code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard `tooltip()` function in jQuery, it's provided by a plugin. Ensure that you're a. loading the plugin and b. loading it after jQuery by placing the `<script>` tag for the plugin after the one for jQuery.

Comment: thanks for the reply. just browsed my codes and it looks like i am not using any plugin for tooltip. cud u pls throw some light on these plugins, which are required for tooltip? thank you.

Comment: @Eashwar jQuery UI provides a `tooltip()` function, which may be the one your code is expecting to be there. Can you include the `<script>` tags you *do* have in the question?

Comment: You were right, there was a plugin which was not loaded by me properly. i just used those plugins by including them within the <script> tags and made sure that they are included after the ones for the jquery. worked great! thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a tool tip plugin for jQuery, but it hasn't been loaded when you make the call.

If this code is being run when the page loads, you should put it into a `$(document).ready()` function, to ensure that all the supporting libraries are loaded before it runs. This should solve the problem.

Comment: I prefer to use `jQuery()` over `$(document).ready()` personally.

Comment: tried inserting my codes within document.ready(), which dint solve my problem. it looks like i am not using any plugin for the tooltip. what kinds of plugins can i use and how do i load em to ensure that they are working fine? thanks.

Comment: @Eashwar - if you're not using a tooltip plugin, then no, the code won't work (in any browser, not just IE). I assume you copied your tooltip code from somewhere? Maybe a tutorial, maybe another site? Whatever, take a look at where you copied it from; the tooltip plugin should be included there.

Comment: @Spudley I wasnt loading the plugin properly. Just ensured that i load the plugins after the ones for the jquery, and it worked great! thanks for your help!!